# 100% Width of a table not filling the page

Tags: html, css

I've made a table to act as a frame to lay my website out on but when I set the width of it to 100% and put a background on it I have an edge on the right hand side that won't fill.

Checkout my website linked to my profile and click on the altwebsite 2 link for what im getting.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="maintable">
    <tr id="firstrow">
        <th id="header" colspan="3">

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="menu" colspan="3">
        <td>
            <?php
                include 'pagecontent/link.php';
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="secondrow">
        <td id="leftcol">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td id="maincol">
            <?php
            include 'pagecontent/main.php';
            ?>
        </td>
        <td id="rightcol">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td id="footer" colspan="3">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I'am trying to keep it all in a separate stylesheet.

Any help would be brilliant thanks

Comment: Can you right click and inspect the source of the area that won't fill? That will help us figure out what's blocking it. Adding a plunkr to this would be ideal (I understand you have a link on your profile, but for security reasons you might find some of us more hesitant)

Comment: Using tables as a page structure is a practice from the 90's, use DIVs if you can

Comment: You can also use the Stack Snippet functionality (click the icon that looks like a page with a pair of brackets on it), since you are using HTML & CSS.

Comment: Don't use tables for layouts. I gotta say it because this isn't 1999.

Answer (score 2):

your `id="header"` and `id="menu"` `[colspan]` is set to **3**, but your `id="secondrow"` has **four** `<td>`

Maybe you want this:

```
<table id="maintable">
    <tr id="firstrow">
        <th id="header" colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="menu">
        <td colspan="3">
            <?php
                include 'pagecontent/link.php';
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="secondrow">
        <td id="leftcol"></td>
        <td id="maincol">
            <?php
            include 'pagecontent/main.php';
            ?>
        </td>
        <td id="rightcol"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="footer" >
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

for your table. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the attribute `width="100%"` in the table tag. This sometimes helps even when the css is set to 100% width.

ALSO:
I recreated the same basic code you used, and it was working fine on my machine so my guess is that you have some sort of surrounding div or tag that the table is taking up 100% of.

Answer (score 0):

First things first i want to say thank you for all the replies, really appreciated.
And yeh i had 4 columns with a colspan of 3 thought i set it to another row. For all those table haters out there it helps me visualise the layout.

And thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your class. It worked for me

```
tbody, tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```